# How does "simultaneous" mode work when changing Azure role instance count only?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-management-api

I'm staring into description of [Change Deployment Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460809.aspx) Azure Management Service operation. There's `Mode` element which can be set to `Simultaneous`.

Suppose I only want to change instance count for a specific role. AFAIK the only way to do that is to obtain the current deployment configuration (using [Get Deployment operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460804.aspx)), locate the role in the obtained XML, locate the attribute responsible for instance count, change that attribute and then use the altered configuration in *Change Deployment Configuration* operation.

Suppose I also set `Mode` to `Simultaneous`. What will be the difference compared to default?

Comment: Given that there's no description provided for `Simultaneous` mode, if I were to speculate the change will be applied to all `Upgrade Domains` simultaneously. Under `Auto` mode, change will be applied on all VMs in a `Upgrade Domain` and then move on to next upgrade domain.

Comment: @GauravMantri What changes are talking about? Then only thing which is changed is the number of instances.

Comment: The same operation can also be used to change configuration setting values. I don't think fabric controller does not differentiate between whether you're changing the instance count or changing the config setting values. That's the change I was talking about. What I have noticed is that any attempt to scale up/down also reboots existing instances.

Comment: @GauravMantri Never witnessed instances being rebooted on scale up/down.

Answer (score 0):

When a configuration change happens (either a normal config change of a config setting, or a scale change) the Azure fabric will walk the upgrade domains one at a time and apply the configuration setting.  With simultaneous upgrade the Azure fabric will apply the configuration change to all instances in all upgrade domains at the same time.

Services which cancel the RoleEnvironment.Changing event in order to recycle the instance during a config change will experience an entire service outage if the mode is set to simultaneous.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/12/07/topology-blast-send-topology-change-updates-to-all-instances-at-once.aspx for more information.

Comment: Suppose my service is not configured to use "topology blast". Can I use "simultaneous" configuration changes?