# meaning of parameter "mode " of set-AzureDeployment

Tags: powershell, azure

What is the meaning of "mode" of set-AzureDeployment?

-Mode
Specifies the mode of upgrade. Supported values are: "Auto", "Manual", and "Simultaneous".

What does "Auto","Manual", and "Simultaneous" mean?

I am particularly interested in "Simultaneous". Does it mean my package will be deployed to multiple instances simultaneously?

Thanks

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-the-release-of-windows-azure-sdk-2-0-for-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773353/how-does-simultaneous-mode-work-when-changing-azure-role-instance-count-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mode specifies the type of update to initiate. Role instances are allocated to update domains when the service is deployed. Updates can be initiated manually in each update domain or initiated automatically in all update domains.

If not specified, the default value is Auto. If set to Manual, WalkUpgradeDomain must be called to apply the update. If set to Auto, the update is automatically applied to each update domain in sequence.

To perform an **automatic update** of a deployment, call Upgrade Deployment or Change Deployment Configuration with the Mode element set to automatic. The update proceeds from that point without a need for further input. You can call Get Operation Status to determine when the update is complete.

To perform a **manual update**, first call Upgrade Deployment with the Mode element set to manual. Next, call Walk Upgrade Domain to update each domain within the deployment. You should make sure that the operation is complete by calling Get Operation Status before updating the next domain. More information please refer to this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9d7e0a75-b9a9-4258-b140-b9425151fb3a/argument-mode-on-setazuredeployment?forum=azurescripting).

One of the new deployment options we now support is the ability to do a “**Simultaneous Update**” of a Cloud Service (we sometimes also refer to this as the “Blast Option”).  When you use this option we bypass the normal upgrade domain walk that is done by default with Cloud Services (where we upgrade parts of the Cloud Service sequentially to avoid ever bringing the entire service down) and we instead upgrade all roles and instances simultaneously. With today’s release this simultaneous update logic now happens within Windows Azure (on the cloud side).  This has the benefit of enabling the Cloud Service update to happen much faster. More information please refer to this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-the-release-of-windows-azure-sdk-2-0-for-net).

> I am particularly interested in "Simultaneous". Does it mean my
>   package will be deployed to multiple instances simultaneously?

The answer is yes.